# Removing nulls from xmltype output

Tags: oracle, xmltype

```
create table xml_type (
  id number,
  xmlval xmlType
);    
/

DECLARE
  l_xmltype xmltype;
BEGIN

  SELECT sys_xmlagg(xmlelement("Emp",xmlforest(e.empno,e.ename,e.sal)))
  INTO l_xmltype
  FROM emp e;

  INSERT INTO xml_type VALUES
    (1, l_xmltype);

END;
/

SELECT extractvalue(value(d),'//EMPNO/text()') AS Empno
 FROM XML_TYPE x
   , TABLE(xmlsequence(extract(X.XMLVAL,'/ROWSET/Emp/*'))) d
```

In this query I am getting two NULLs after every empno returned, Why is this happening?

I am trying to understand xmltype and handling XML data types in the database.

Comment: What does the data in the table EMP look like? Do you have NULLs in there?

Comment: @Ben  it's the emp table in Scott schema. Please run the above query and you will understand what I am talking about